# Error while Upgrading my app from WP8 to WP8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, upgrade, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting the following error

```
 Error 5  The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
 System.InvalidOperationException: Item named 'themes/generic.xaml' of
 type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource
 file because it is not serializable.    at
 Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
 reader, IResourceWriter writer)    at
 Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
 reader, String filename)    at
 Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile,
 String outFileOrDir)    at
 Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log,
 ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs, Boolean
 sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String
 resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean
 publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory) 
 at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper
 log, ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 outputs,
 Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String
 resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean
 publicClass, Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory) 
 at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()    at
 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
 at
 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
 WPAPP
```

I am not able figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831850/windows-8-store-app-with-windows-phone-app)

Comment: I have checked it but I working on same platform WP8 and WP8.1 not on Windows 8,this should not raise the problem?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am having very similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using reference of some dll or something from WP8 to WP8.1 and which is not supported in WP8.1.Do remove that references from the project.

Comment: Thanks but I am still facing the issue. In that case I would get some warning that this class has been deprecated but I am not getting any such warning moreover I have checked the references that am using are supported in wp 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Removing the reference of System.windows.controls did the trick for me.